# Visual Basic Bug For SQL Stored Procedure in Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I need to create an excel macro where people can put in their parameters from a stored proc in SQL server. There is a bug somewhere on line 13, but I am not sure what it is since I am very new to Visual Basic.

Any help would be very appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim TransTime As Date  'Declare the SellStartDate as Date
Dim StoreNumber As Integer    'Declare the SellEndDate as Date
Dim Product As Integer    'Declare the SellEndDate as Date

TransTime = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value   'Pass value from cell B3 to SellStartDate variable
StoreNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value     'Pass value from cell B4 to SellEndDate variable
Product = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B6").Value     'Pass value from cell B4 to SellEndDate variable

'Pass the Parameters values to the Stored Procedure used in the Data Connection
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("nitro_price_check").ODBCConnection
CommandText = "EXEC maverik.nitro_price_check '" & TransTime & "','" & StoreNumber & "'" & Product & "'"
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("nitro_price_check").Refresh
    
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: *"There is a bug somewhere on line 13"* A serious and fatal one at that; SQL Injection. Learn to parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: `'" & TransTime & "','" & StoreNumber & "'" & Product & "'"` will end up as `'12:34','32'45'`, you are missing a comma and another `'` between StoreNumber and Product. Easier to help though if you show the result of `MsgBox CommandText` or something, or provide the exact error message instead of "a bug."

Comment: You are missing the period qualifier before `CommandText`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, consider parameterization which is supported with Excel workbook connections but initial setup requires going through Excel's user interface. See MSDN docs for [Create a parameter query in Microsoft Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-parameter-query-in-microsoft-query-c67d9af7-c8a0-4bf7-937c-087cb25f7ad3).

During setup, be sure to include qmarks in your SQL command (i.e., Command Text):

```sql
EXEC maverik.nitro_price_check ?, ?, ?
```

This will enable `Parameters...` button under Definition tab of Connection Properties,  where you can assign Excel cell values to each qmark placeholder by corresponding position:

- Parameters ...

  - Parameter 1 `=Sheet1!B4`
  - Parameter 2 `=Sheet1!B5`
  - Parameter 3 `=Sheet1!B6`

Then your VBA is just a simple refresh line with no messy concatenation or quotation with SQL:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("nitro_price_check").Refresh
End Sub
```